# Fourier transforms established by the Fourier' integral theorem

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

Recently, I saw the Fourier transform established by the Fourier's integral theorem in *"Integral\, transforms\, for Engineers"* (p 50). Specifically, the exponential form of Fourier's integral theorem is 
$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-isx}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ist}f(t)\,dt\,ds
$$

Then the Fourier transform are defined as
\begin{align}
F(s)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ist}f(t)dt
\\
f(t)&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ist}F(s)ds
\end{align}
However, the pair of Fourier transforms are often shown as follows
\begin{align}
F(s)&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ist}f(t)dt
\\
f(t)&=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ist}F(s)ds
\end{align}
Are these two forms the same essentially and why (especially for the index of Fourier transform and inverse Fourier transform)?

Comment: Just different conventions. https://www.johndcook.com/blog/fourier-theorems/, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Other_conventions

Comment: You can use either convention. Complete agreement among Mathematicians on the constant factor  in  a Fourier transform id not there and different authors use different factors. There is also no agreement on wether you should have $e^{ist}$ or $e^{-ist} $ in the definition.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy : An interpretation making the sign choice seem natural is that you represent the function as "sum" of oscillations, $$f(t)=C\int_{\Bbb R} \hat f(w)e^{iwt}dw.$$ The Fourier "coefficients" are then obtained via "scalar product", $$\hat f(w)=\langle f,e_w\rangle=C'\int_{\Bbb R}f(t)\overline{e^{iwt}}\,dt.$$ (The quotes are because the $e_w(t)=e^{iwt}$ are not $L^2$ functions.)